# moment.js black friday this month boolean

Tags: momentjs

I want to make a js function. When I input year and month number, if there is a black friday in that month, it will returns true. 
Is there any simlar moment.js method or function to do this? Thx.

Comment: Is black Friday the last Friday of November?

Comment: What is a black Friday? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, I mean "Friday the 13th", not the november or october that one.
I tried parse year and month and check 13th is friday or not, but I want to know is there any better idea, thx.

Comment: You should edit your question explaining that you want to check if the given month has "Friday the 13th", and add your **code attempt**.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a moment object representing the 13th of the given month using using [`moment({unit: value, ...});`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/) then you can get day of week using [`day()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/). As [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) says:

> This method can be used to set the day of the week, with Sunday as 0 and Saturday as 6.

so you can check if `day()` is equal to 5 (Friday).

Here a working example:

```js
function hasBlackFriday(year, month) {
  return (moment({y: year, M: month, d: 13}).day() === 5);
}

// Test foreach month of 2017
for(var i=0; i<12; i++){
  console.log(hasBlackFriday(2017, i));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Keep in mind that, as [`moment({unit: value, ...});`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/) docs says:

> Note that like `moment(Array)` and `new Date(year, month, date)`, months are 0 indexed.

---

As Matt Johnson highlighted in the comments, you can get the same result also using native JavaScript Date object, here a sample:

```js
function hasBlackFriday(year, month) {
  return (new Date(year, month, 13).getDay() === 5);
}

// Test foreach month of 2017
for(var i=0; i<12; i++){
  console.log(hasBlackFriday(2017, i));
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach.  Also note that you don't even really need Moment for this.  The `Date` object has similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the date for last Friday of the given month `m` and year `y`.

```
    function hasBlackFriday(y, m) {
      var date = moment(new Date(y, m - 1, '1'))

      result = date.endOf('month');
      while (result.day() !== 5) {
        result.subtract(1, 'day');
      }
      return result;
    }

    console.log(hasBlackFriday(2017, 4).format('M DD YY'))
```